# Const correctness and shared_ptr conversions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, constants, shared-ptr

Let's say I have following types:

```
using pointer = std::shared_ptr<MyType>;
using pointer_to_const = std::shared_ptr<const MyType>;
```

Now, if I have piece of code like the following:

```
void fun(pointer_to_const ptr);

pointer myObj = SomeFactoryMethod();
fun(myObj);
```

Is there an automatic conversion between `pointer` and `pointer_to_const`? And if there is, would the underlying `MyType` object be copied during this conversion?

Because if there is a conversion, and there's no copy, then in a multithreaded context another thread could use the original `myObj` pointer to modify the underlying object, thus violating the `const` which is expected by `fun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such conversion can be done and will be shallow copy of pointer and control block (ref count).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work. Following constructor of `shared_ptr` will be called:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r );
```

With `Y` deduced to be `const MyType`.